# openform button with filter condition in ms-access

Tags: ms-access

access master. I've create form and button below it, the button is `openform`. What I want to ask is, how to `openform` with filter condition got from `main form` `textbox`. please and many thanks,.....

Comment: Do you want it by `VBA codes` or by `Macro Actions`?

Comment: `VBA Codes` is more expert than `macro`, I think!

Comment: So, below answer should work for you! Do you check that?

Comment: @harun24hr sorry for late reply, I had using both of these two codes. And both of these are not working,..... it returned unfiltered showing all records. What information do you needed.

Comment: I tested the codes in a file and then gave you, so no chance to fail. I am sharing the sample file. [(Download Sample File From Here)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByUqUZQzUv2tOU5rM2pVdlVPejg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Let me know what happens with sample file. I also suggest to share a sample file with me so that I can check your code.

Comment: wow,.. great thanks a lot,... I'll use it for experimental,....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By using VBA:**

```
Private Sub cmdVBA_Click()
 DoCmd.OpenForm "frmSalary", acFormDS, "", "[EmpID]='" & Me.EmpID & "'", , acNormal
 'DoCmd.OpenForm "frmSalary", acFormDS, "", "[EmpID]='" & [Forms]![frmMain]![EmpID] & "'", , acNormal
End Sub
```

*Here `frmMain` is main form and `frmSalary` is opening form.*

**By using macro actions.**

Where condition is=

```
="[EmpID]='" & Nz([EmpID],0) & "'"
```

*See the following screenshot.*

[image]

Comment: Note: `acFormDS` for `Datasheet View`. If you want to preview then use `acPreview` rather than `acFormDS` in command.